# What is the difference between sudo -s and sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I'm trying to start JupyterHub using the command `sudo jupyterhub`. This starts the server but the user is not able to login. But when I switch to the root user using `sudo -s` and then type jupyterhub, everything works perfectly.

What is the difference between running a command by typing `sudo` before it and switching to the root user using `sudo -s` and then running the command.

My main objective is to add this command to /etc/rc.local so that jupyterhub starts automatically on system startup and runs in background. Now how can I add `sudo -s` there?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score -1):

Let's say your default shell is `zsh` and root's shell is `bash`. When you run `sudo -s` sudo will launch a `zsh` rather than `bash`.

The default shell is configured in `/etc/passwd`. Please check `man sudo`.

Comment: How do I know what my default shell is?

Comment: As I said, it is configured in `/etc/passwd`. `echo "${SHELL}"` will work too

Comment: I just checked my `/etc/passwd`. shell for both root and my user (ubuntu) are `/bin/bash`. Then why there's this difference?

Comment: Which difference? If `root` and your user both have their default shell set to `/bin/bash`, `sudo -s` will have just no effect.

Comment: jupyterhub is working when I run `jupyterhub` after running `sudo -s` but not wihen I just run `sudo jupyterhub`

Comment: I see. Hard to say from remote. The `-s` option is just affecting the shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146067/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-p0712).

Comment: Ok. Anyway, if I want to add `sudo -s` in `/etc/rc.local` how can I do it. Because adding `sudo jupyterhub` is not working

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote here? What I said is true